# Pear (SMTP) Mail.php won't send, No errors

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to use PEAR's Mail.php to send email with SMTP through a cPanel mail server (running on a hosted server)

The script is on the same server as the mail server.

I'm getting no errors, but I'm also not getting any mail, and I don't know why :/

My code:

**Email.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("include_path", '/home/gamerfin/php:'); 

require_once "Mail.php";

class Email{

function mailClient(){
    return Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://mail.gamerfinder.net',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'debug' => true,
        'username' => 'messenger@gamerfinder.net', //your gmail account
        'password' => '*********' // your password
    ));

}

function send(){}

function newMessageMail($sender, $email, $message){
    echo $email;
    $smtp = self::mailClient();
    $from = 'messenger@gamerfinder.net'; //change this to your email address
    $to = $email; // change to address
    $subject = 'New Message from '.$sender; // subject of mail
    $body = "You have recieved a new message from ".$sender."<br>Message:<br>".$message; //content of mail

    $headers = array(
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $email,
        'Subject' => $subject
    );
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    var_dump ($mail);
}
}

?>
```

Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong?

I've looked at other questions and tried some of their answers, but no luck :/

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's the mail debug log:

```
DEBUG: Recv: 220-cloud536.unlimitedwebhosting.co.uk ESMTP Exim 4.89 #1 Fri, 25 Aug 2017 23:52:55 +0100 
DEBUG: Recv: 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
DEBUG: Recv: 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
DEBUG: Send: EHLO localhost

DEBUG: Recv: 250-cloud536.unlimitedwebhosting.co.uk Hello localhost [149.255.60.167]
DEBUG: Recv: 250-SIZE 52428800
DEBUG: Recv: 250-8BITMIME
DEBUG: Recv: 250-PIPELINING
DEBUG: Recv: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
DEBUG: Recv: 250 HELP
DEBUG: Send: AUTH LOGIN

DEBUG: Recv: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
DEBUG: Send: bWVzc2VuZ2VyQGdhbWVyZmluZGVyLm5ldA==

DEBUG: Recv: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
DEBUG: Send: ***************

DEBUG: Recv: 235 Authentication succeeded
DEBUG: Send: MAIL FROM:
<messenger@gamerfinder.net>
  DEBUG: Recv: 250 OK
    DEBUG: Send: RCPT TO:
  <jamiemac262@gmail.com>
    DEBUG: Recv: 250 Accepted
    DEBUG: Send: DATA

DEBUG: Recv: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
DEBUG: Send: From: messenger@gamerfinder.net
To: ***********@gmail.com
Subject: New Message from jamiemac262


DEBUG: Send: You have recieved a new message from jamiemac262<br>
Message:<br>
jamiemac262 has accepted your request to play Elite Dangerous
DEBUG: Send: 
.

DEBUG: Recv: 250 OK id=1dlNTD-0006DI-TS
DEBUG: Send: QUIT

DEBUG: Recv: 221 cloud536.unlimitedwebhosting.co.uk closing connection
```

Comment: Please reset your password ASAP. Also, did you check the spam folder or are there any 'Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender' emails in the gamerfinder inbox? Gmail can be picky.

Comment: My password isn't listed on there?... or did I skip that line? (I do that sometimes haha)

Comment: It was listed base64 encoded..

Comment: I've checked, There are no emails in the gmail trash/junk/(every folder on my gmail), and there is no record of the email on gamerfinder (neither as a "failed to deliver" or in the sent/junk mailboxes)

Comment: ah, I'll get that changed now

Comment: Hmm I really cant see where the problem is either... the log looks alright. Care to try a email delivery testing tool? https://app.glockapps.com/ is awesome for that.

Comment: I just tried the glockapps, none of the emails were sent from the script, but I think that might be because of the top of the logs, where it says `DEBUG: Recv: 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
DEBUG: Recv: 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
`.... ?

Comment: I think I've found the problem, My IP address is blacklisted on every email server. I ran the test on the server rather than through the script

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was afraid of. Make sure you remove your server from all blacklists. Set the correct spoof and DKIM records. I'm sure you can google most of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem.

The problem was that I was generating a spam score of 2.0, and my host was blocking anything with a spam score of 2 or higher.

My host was kind enough to send me the mail gateway logs which told me what was causing the spam score.

I was able to fix this by adding a name to the `from` header, and adding a `date` header

```
'From' => '"Gamer Finder" <messenger@gamerfinder.net>',
        'To' => 'email@gmail.com',
        'Subject' => $subject,
        'Date'  => date("r")
```

So for anyone who has similar issues, do a little research and find out what can trigger spam rules and make sure you aren't triggering them :)